# Multiple Calendars integration using Cordova

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, calendar

I am using cordova and ionic for my android app. I am in need to integrate multiple calendars to add events to different calendars.

I have checked few other apps which populates the list of accounts added in the Android device and the event gets added to the selected account from the populated list. [account can be google/outlook etc.]

I wonder if there is any way achieve the same as above using cordova. I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-calendar which allows me to add to the default calendar in the device. But I need to populate all the accounts added in the device and add events to selected account calendar.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To select a specific calendar, you first need to list the available calendars using `listCalendars()`. 
You can use this to present a list of available calendars to the user and enable them to select one.
Once the user has chosen a calendar, you then pass its details to `createEventWithOptions()` when you are creating the event.

For example, something like this:

```
var calendars = [];

var selectedCalendar;

var onDeviceReady = function(){
    window.plugins.calendar.listCalendars(function(_calendars){
        _calendars.forEach(function(_calendar){
            if(cordova.platformId === "android"){
                // Omit Contacts from Android calendar list
                if(!_calendar.name.match(/Contacts/i)){
                    calendars.push(_calendar);
                }
            }else{ //cordova.platformId === "ios"
                // Omit Birthdays and Subscriptions as they are read-only
                if(!_calendar.type.match(/Subscription/i) && !_calendar.type.match(/Birthday/i)){
                    calendars.push(_calendar);
                }
            }
        });
    }, function(err){
        console.error('Error listing calendars: ' + err);
    });
};
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Call this to display the list of available calendars for the user to choose from
// TODO implement calendar picker UI
var displayCalendars = function(){
    calendars.forEach(function(calendar){
        var id = calendar.id;
        var name = calendar.name;
        var displayName = calendar.displayname || calendar.name;

        //TODO generate calendar picker UI entry
    });
};


// TODO call this when user has selected a calendar entry in the picker UI
var selectCalendar = function(id, name){
    selectedCalendar = {
        id: id,
        name: name
    };
}

// TODO call this to add event to selected calendar
var createEvent = function(title, location, startDateTime, endDateTime, notes){
    // Generate options for selected calendar
    var calOptions = window.plugins.calendar.getCalendarOptions();
    calOptions.calendarId = selectedCalendar.id;
    calOptions.calendarName = selectedCalendar.name;

    // Add event to selected calendar
    window.plugins.calendar.createEventWithOptions(
        title,
        location,
        notes,
        startDateTime,
        endDateTime,
        calOptions,
        function(){
            console.log("Successfully added to calendar");
        },
        function(err){
            console.error("Error adding to calendar: " + err);
        }
    );
};
```

Comment: window.plugins.calendar.createEventInteractively() worked perfectly for me.. Your answer helped me to explore the plugin more.. +1 :)